# How can I install MAAS 1.9?

Tags: 16.04, maas

How can I install specific version of maas , consider as 1.9?

UBUNTU 16.04

I noticed MAAS 2.0.0 Beta4 not support juju until MAAS 2.0.0 Beta 7.

Until then I need:

1) Install MAAS 1.9 on my machine

I can find MAAS 1.9 related package here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/maas/1.9.0+bzr4533-0ubuntu1

2) As you know Ubuntu 16.04 default MAAS is 2.0.0 and dependent package python is python3

3) How can I install MAAS 1.9 and Python 2.7 on UBUNTU 16.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Download the 1.9 tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/maas/1.9.0+bzr4533-0ubuntu1)
- Uncompress it using `tar -xvf FILENAME.tar.gz`
- Move the extracted file to `/usr/local/share/MAAS-1.9` by doing `sudo mv /path/to/unzipped/folder /usr/local/share/MAAS-1.9`
- Link any executables that you need to run MAAS by doing `sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/MAAS-1.9/path/to/executable /usr/local/bin/executable`

There maybe be dependencies or other things that you will need to get, but this is the direct and raw way to get MAAS v1.9.

Comment: Thanks, could you please help me more about last part "Link any executables that you need to run MAAS by doing" , if there is any link with step by step please let me know.

Comment: I haven't downloaded and installed this MAAS 1.9 myself, but I have done this for other programs. What is the executable in the extracted MAAS folder? (ie, what do you execute to run MAAS?) I'm not sure what MAAS is or how it runs, so this is where you'd have to fill me in. The purpose of the last bullet is so that you can "run" maas from anywhere by taking any executable files in the maas folder and creating a link to them from the `/usr/local/bin` directory using the `ln` command. Hope this clears some confusion.